# Use part of file name as variable

Tags: batch-file

I need to get a certain part of the file name and use that as a variable in a batch file.

Each file will have the following structure: "name_surname$code".

My goal is to get all text after the $ sign.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

** Edit **
Code I have so far

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
md out
for /f %%G in ('dir /b "*.pdf"') do (
    call:_pwgen passwd
    pdftk %%G output out/%%G user_pw !passwd!
)

goto :EOF

:_pwgen passwd
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set _RNDLength=8
set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
set passwd=%~1
set _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
set /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
set _count=0
set _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
set /a _count+=1
set _RND=%Random%
set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
set _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
if !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
set passwd=!_RndAlphaNum!
endlocal&set %~1=%passwd%
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Do you have a batch file where this code needs added? Can you show that?

Comment: I need the code to form part of the pdf document password. The only code I have generates a random password. 'code'setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set _RNDLength=8
set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
set passwd=%~1
set _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
set /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
set _count=0
set _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
set /a _count+=1
set _RND=%Random%
set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
set _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
if !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
set passwd=!_RndAlphaNum!
endlocal&set %~1=%passwd%'code'

Comment: Please tell me you are not going to protect files with passwords based on their names... and [edit] your post to include code, instead of posting it in comments.#

Comment: Unfortunately, this is exactly what I will be doing. Obviously removing the code section from the file name before sending the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably against best practice recommendations:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
md out
for /f %%G in ('dir /b "*.pdf"') do (
    for /f "delims=$ tokens=1*" %%H in ("%%~nG") do set "partial_filename=%%~I"
    call:_pwgen passwd
    pdftk %%G output out/%%G user_pw !passwd!
)

goto :EOF

:_pwgen passwd
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
echo You can use %partial_filename% here as you see fit.
...
```